# Wrap everything between two tag occurrences with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, libxslt

I want to split an XML (actually, XHTML) document in sections by the top-level `h1` tags. Everything starting at the first of `<h1>` up to the next one should be wrapped in `<section>` element and so on, until the end of the document.

For example, if I have this source document:

```
<article>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Some more text</p>

    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Some text</p>

    <h1 id="heading3">Heading 3</h1>
    <p>Some text</p>
</article>
```

I want the result to be exactly like this:

```
<article>
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some more text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>Heading 2</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <h2>Subheading</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1 id="heading3">Heading 3</h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

The problem is all I have is libxslt1.1 (thus, XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT). With XSLT 2.0 I could've do something with a nice-looking `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1">` but, sadly, it's not a viable option for me.

I don't want to group on attribute values (I don't have any meaningful attributes), so, as I understand it, Muenchian grouping is not a trick that would work for me. Maybe I'm wrong, though - I've only read about this method some minutes ago.

Is there any way to achieve this with XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> as I understand it, Muenchian grouping is not a trick that would work
>   for me.

Well, something very close to it will:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grpById" match="*[not(self::h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="h1">
            <section>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('grpById', generate-id())"/>
            </section>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works flawlessly! I didn't knew about `generate-id(preceding-sibling::h1[1])`. Always good to learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

Use a key `name="group" match="article/*[not(self::h1)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::h1)"`, then in the template matching `article` apply templates to the `h1` child elements and in the template for `h1` create the section and copy `.|key('group', position())`.